# How to make HTML <video> tag show black during screen capture?

Tags: html, html5-video

On sites like Udemy.com, if you try to take a video of the browser or a screenshot, even if the browser doesn't have focus, the video player shows as a black rectangle instead of showing the content of the video.  They are displaying the video using a  HTML `<video>` tag.  How is this accomplished?

[image]

Comment: Mind showing a photo?

Comment: I just enrolled to test this and when I screen cap it I get the video. Sounds like a video driver issue

Comment: This is a brand new feature of the site that just started today, as far as I can tell.  I've always been able to take screenshots before.  And  no drivers have been changed.  Sure I'll get a photo, @James  And yes Clive, that may indeed be what's going on here.  I just tested Netflix, and it is very similar behavior.  Thanks.

Comment: @David, I don't think JS have the functionality to detect screenshot like an (eventListener) or screen cpature, but a possible solution I could think about is to check user's keyboard typing since in PC we use shortcut to take screenshot or screen capature